# update table set column=a-b

Tags: mysql, sql

My products table with stocks column, I want to update the stocks wtih the value for (product available-quantity ordered). What update query must I use? Getting error with the following query

How should i code this part -- set stocks=prod-qty????

```
public boolean updateProductWhenInsertintoCart(Product p) {


        try
        {
            Connection con=DbConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select shopping_cart_final.quantity, products.stocks from shopping_cart_final,products where shopping_cart_final.itemName=products.itemName");
            //ps.setString(1,p.getItemName());
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            int qty=0;
            int prod=0;
            System.out.println(rs);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("in while loop");
                qty=rs.getInt("quantity");
                prod=rs.getInt("stocks");
                System.out.println("quantity "+qty);
                System.out.println("stocks "+prod);
                p.setDiff(prod-qty);
                int d = p.getDiff();
            }

            String sql="Update products set stocks=prod-qty where itemName=?";
            PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps1.setString(1, p.getItemName());
            //ps1.setInt(1,p.getStocks());


            int x=ps1.executeUpdate();
            if(x>0)
            {
            return true;    
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Add error message as well

Comment: it's not clear what your intention is. Do you want to update that entire table or some selected items?

Comment: without the error message its hard to tell

Comment: instead of computing via the script why not send the computed value? In which i saw you already made it by int d = p.getDiff();. Why not just pass the d on the sql script?

Comment: Even if I pass the int d to update the stocks it gives an error...